# jquery mobile - disabled select highlights IE 10/11

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile. Active state of all inputs has a shade of green color. In IE 10 and 11, even though I disable the select menus using

```
$("selector :input").prop('disabled', true);   
$("selector").addClass('ui-disabled');
```

These select menus are changing color (to the active color green, even though they are not selectable) if they are clicked in IE 10 and 11.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening? Thanks in advance!

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g5vgfec3/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#select-menu-id").selectmenu("disable");
```

worked.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g5vgfec3/5/

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why/how this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they are not as easy to learn from as code with an explanation. Without an explanation it takes considerably more time and effort to understand what was being done, the changes made to the code, or if the code is useful.  The explanation is important both for people attempting to learn from the answer and those evaluating the answer to see if it is valid, or worth up voting.